# Add value to OAuth2PasswordRequestForm in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

i want the client to pass aditional information while loggin in to FastApi. I think for that i have to change the scheme for OAuth2PasswordRequestForm. Can anyone explain how to do that?

Im using the code from the FastApi tutorial right now:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to have the user pass the info required by OAuth2PasswordRequestForm and also include some extra required information.
The easiest way to do this would probably be to create your own scheme that is a subclass of OAuth2PasswordRequestForm.

```py
    import fastapi
    from fastapi import Depends
    from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
    
    app = fastapi.FastAPI()

    class ExtendedOAuth2PasswordRequestForm(OAuth2PasswordRequestForm):
        extra_data_field: str

    @app.post("/your_endpoint")
    def login_for_access_token(form_data: ExtendedOAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
        #do stuff with all of the normal OAuth2PasswordRequestForm and your extra data field...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add extend parameter to body request as follow:
[image]

And add the parameter to form data in frontend part:
[image]